# Can extension replace delegation in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning delegation in swift. This paragraph uses example to explain how delegation works.

> In this simple example, I want to ensure that my app’s root view
>   controller, a UINavigationController, doesn’t permit the app to rotate
>   — the app should appear only in portrait orientation when this view
>   controller is in charge. But UINavigation‐ Controller isn’t my class;
>   it belongs to Cocoa. My own class is a different view controller, a
>   UIViewController subclass, which acts as the UINavigationController’s
>   child. How can the child tell the parent how to rotate? Well, 
>   UINavigationController has a delegate property, typed as
>   UINavigationControllerDelegate (a protocol). It promises to send this
>   delegate the navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations
>   message when it needs to know how to rotate.

My question: Can we extend myOwnViewController to have method "navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations" to replace the delegation pattern to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `myOwnViewController`, tell extension to conform to `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol and implement method that you want, however this does not replace the delegation pattern. If your extension does not conform to this delegate's protocol, you won't be able to attach `myOwnViewController` as `UINavigationController's` delegate.

```
class MyController: UIViewController {
}

extension MyController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .Portrait
    }
}
let navigationController = UINavigationController()
let controller = MyController()
navigationController.delegate = controller
```

Same result can be achieved by telling `MyController` class to conform to `UINavigationControllerDelegate`protocol.

```
class MyController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .Portrait
    }

}
let navigationController = UINavigationController()
let controller = MyController()
navigationController.delegate = controller
```

Those two examples result in `MyController` being the delegate for your `UINavigationController`. This can lead to having many responsibilities in one place. In order to split this responsibility, you can create another class that will be the delegate for your navigation controller.

```
class MyController: UIViewController {}

class NavigationDelegate: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations(navigationController: UINavigationController) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .Portrait
    }

}
let navigationController = UINavigationController()
let controller = MyController()
let navigationDelegate = NavigationDelegate()
navigationController.delegate = navigationDelegate
```

What is the difference? Imagine that you have implemented a complex logic for your supported orientation method and you find out that you don't use `MyController` any more, instead, you will use `DifferentController`. Since your orientation logic is in `MyController`, you would need to create it anyway. However, if your delegate logic is separated in `NavigationDelegate` class, you can use `DifferentController` without need of creating `MyController` class just for these delegate methods.

Comment: Could you compare the two ways: use extension and the original way described in the paragraph?

Comment: I've updated the comment with comparison. I hope this will make it more clear to understand.

Comment: Another question: why not `UINavigationController` contain `navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations' method itself? Same reason? For the flexibility?

Comment: If `UINavigationController` had this method, then you would have to inherit from `UINavigationController` and override it. This would make your logic tightly coupled to this certain class. With delegate pattern, you can easily inject it to navigation controller. Imagine that you have two subclasses of navigation controllers that print something different when `viewDidLoad` is called, but share the same supported orientation logic. With delegate pattern, you can inject that `NavigationDelegate` class to both subclasses instead of having the same code in two places.

Comment: I am trying to come up with a concrete example. If we don't have delegate pattern, we could simply call `myVC. navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations == .Portrait `. In delegation pattern, we have to do much more things. So I am not clear about the last sentence in the last comment. Although we have same code in two places, it looks still shorter and neater.

Comment: Good question. What if this value depends on current controller presented in this navigation controller? Then you would have to check it somehow and having this delegate method would allow to do it nicely. Of course in some cases having this one property would be just fine, but it's hard to have optimal solution for every case.